# CI: Image Upload to Folder Not Working

Tags: image, codeigniter, upload

I’m having difficulty determining what I’m doing wrong/how to troubleshoot it, when attempting to use the upload library.  I have a form with multiple fields (mostly text), with one image upload field.  Data entered into the text fields is properly populated into my database, but the image file that the user browses to to upload, is not showing up in the folder I create at the root, its permissions permit it to be written to.  All help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Partial view below:

```
<p>
               <label for="uEventFillByDateTime">Event Fill-by Date/Time:</label>
               <input type="text" id="uEventFillByDateTime" name="uEventFillByDateTime" />

           </p>
           <p>
               <label for="uEventImage">Event Image:</label>
                <?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>
                <input type="file" name="uEventImage" size="20" id="uEventImage" />
           </p>

           <p>
               <label for="uEventKeywords">Event Keywords:</label>
               <textarea id="uEventKeywords" name="uEventKeywords"></textarea>
           </p>
```

Controller call:

```
public function createEvent() {
                if( !empty( $_POST ) ) {
                    echo $this->event_model->createEvent();
                }
        }
```

Model Code:

```
public function createEvent() {

            $this->image_path = realpath(APPPATH . 'event_images');

            $config = array(
            'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png',
            'upload_path' => $this->image_path,
            'max_size' => 2000,
            'max_width' => 212,
            'max_height' => 118
        );

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->do_upload();
            $image_data = $this->upload->data();

            /*format date time from string to mysql */
            $cdt = $this->input->post( 'cEventDateTime', true );
            $cdtMySQL = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($cdt));
            /*format fill-by date time from string to mysql */
            $cfdt = $this->input->post( 'cEventFillByDateTime', true );
            $cfdtMySQL = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($cfdt));

            $data = array(
                'event_name'  => $this->input->post( 'cEventName', true ),
                'event_datetime' => $cdtMySQL,
                'event_fillbydatetime' => $cfdtMySQL,
                'event_keywords'  => $this->input->post( 'cEventKeywords', true ),
                'event_notes'  => $this->input->post( 'cEventNotes', true ),
                'event_featured'  => $this->input->post( 'cEventFeatured', true ),
                'fk_venue_id'  => $this->input->post( 'cEventVenue', true ),
                'fk_eventtype_id'  => $this->input->post( 'cEventType', true ),
                'fk_eventlifecycle_id'  => $this->input->post( 'cEventlifecycle', true ),
            );
            $this->db->insert( 'event', $data );
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your destination path probably needs a trailing slash, try this:

```
$this->image_path = realpath(APPPATH . 'event_images/');
```

Try playing with the path, from the manual:

> **upload_path**: The path to the folder where the upload should be placed. The folder must be writable and the path can be absolute or relative.

In general, **never assume success**.
You can also get the error messages after you run `do_upload()` like so:

```
$this->upload->display_errors();
```

That should help you resolve the error, or at least figure out why CI isn't uploading the image.

Other things to try:

- Try running `var_dump(is_dir($path))` on the upload path and see what php says.
- Try removing the use of `realpath()`.
- Try a `./path/like/this` as used in the example on the docs page.

**Another note**: You really shouldn't be uploading anything directly into your application or system directory, and any files there should not be accessible directly via http. It's common practice and probably wise to create a separate `/uploads` directory.

If all else fails, have another read through the docs in case you missed something:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Answer (score 0):

You should did validation in your controller first, before sending it to your model... Shortly, put the uploading proccess in your controller function, then after success, you can send the post data into your model.